# Download handler (php code) is called multiple times for a single request

Tags: javascript, php, get-request

I have a PHP script which handles the download requests. this script can be accessed by the client using a GET request like this (Javascript):

```
if (true)
{
  window.open('/download?mode=paper&fid=' + fid, '_blank');
  return;
}
```

And here is the (simplified) handler:

```
function downloadPaper($fid)
{
    // Adds a record to the database, but it seems to be called multiple times
    Daban\PaperTools::addPaperDownloadRecord($fid);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fakeFileName");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

    $fh = fopen($file, "rb");
    while (!feof($fh))
    {
        echo fgets($fh);
        flush();
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

The problem is that according to the database, there are **multiple download records** for each download. In other words, the handler is called multiple times for a single request (or at least that is what I believe).
P.S. **addPaperDownloadRecord()** is jsut some piece of SQL code and it is not the culprit. I also checked the client side, it sends only once.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `handle` called multiple times ( try to add some `echo` to see how many times it's called)? Or it could be the method `addPaperDownloadRecord`?

Comment: Start by verifying how many requests are actually made by the client, using browser dev tools network panel.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the reason. If anyone has a similar problem, this may help. Since I had a download manager in my system, it sent multiple requests to divide the file in order to expedite the download process.